# htmlentities and htmlspecialchars... how to always use them when using echo? e.g. overwrite echo function?

Tags: php, escaping

i have an application with say, 150 pages and lets just say 2000 input fields, textareas and select boxes. Now all input fields call the raw function echo on the data.

e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="in_county" value="<? echo $citiesRow["county"]; ?>">
```

whereas actually all function should call something like

```
<input type="text" name="in_county" value="<? echo htmlspecialchars($citiesRow["county"] , ENT_COMPAT , "ISO-8859-1"); ?>">
```

now I could go to all 150 pages and change / replace all 2000 fields

now well, doing this all over the project sucks, right?
I could, i guess, just overwrite the echo function somehow (?) and be good. Or search replace all `echo` calls with `mysaveechofunction()`

what would be your approach?

bonus question:
is there a reason, not to use htmlspecialchars on ALL echos all over the web application?

Comment: it is impossible to "overwrite echo" since `echo` is not a function, but a language construct. I would go for your 2nd approach and replace it with a custom function.

Comment: 2nd option.... _well that should have been done in the 1st place while writing them_

Comment: `echo` is not reserved for printing to an HTML page. If it were possible to "override" it to automatically escape *HTML* every time you used it, it would be a disaster and corrupt all kinds of data. Plus, of course, you could never use it to print HTML code...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ob_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) in the begin of the code and [ob_get_clean()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) at the end.

ob_start() buffers everything that should be shown (echos, any code out of php tags, print_r, var_dump, etc.).

ob_get_clean() ends the buffering and returns everything that was buffered, save that in a variable and manipulate it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using output buffering is that you will remove all valid html tags also.

I use the following function:

```
function _O($str) { return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); }
```

Just use this when outputting all user submitted strings.

Answer (score -1):

First of all let me tell you that you have a very good eye. Autoescaping is quite recent discovery in PHP world. And extremely valuable one.

Second, you should think of fallback mode, where you need raw output or some different formatting (as htmlspecialchars is not a silver bullet, you know).

Now to your problem.

Unfortunately, inability to autoescape out of the box is, probably, one of biggest drawbacks of native PHP templates. So, even being biggest supporter of them, I would strongly suggest you to use **Twig**, which have the feature already.

But if you still want to use native PHP, then you will need two things

1. Strict rule for passing only scalars and regular arrays into template. No lazy-loading models at all!
2. You will need simple template handler which will allow you to set variables for the template and render it using this data set. So, haveing a commonplace method like this

   ```
   tpl::set('name', $variable, FLAGS);
   ```

you can set your template variables and flexibly control their escaping.

Comment: +1 for mentioning twig. THe second part, i didnt understand at all though